# 'as' flag of Node.js fs.open and fs.openSync

Tags: node.js, fs

In [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags), there's an `'as'` flag for opening files :

> 'a': Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not
> exist.
>
> 'as': Open file for appending in synchronous mode. The file is
> created if it does not exist.

Does it mean that `'as'` flag should be used in place of `'a'` when using `openSync` instead of `open` ?

Or should be used when using `writeSync` instead of `write` ?

Or does it mean written data are not buffered ?

Or anything else ?

It is not very clear ...

Answer (score 0):

It is to :

> Instructs the operating system to bypass the local file system cache

But not fully clear how to open the file ...

Extract of the rs+ flag documentation :

> `'rs+'`: Open file for reading and writing in synchronous mode.
> Instructs the operating system to bypass the local file system cache.
>
> This is primarily useful for opening files on NFS mounts as it allows
> skipping the potentially stale local cache. It has a very real impact
> on I/O performance so using this flag is not recommended unless it is
> needed.
>
> This doesn't turn fs.open() or fsPromises.open() into a synchronous
> blocking call. If synchronous operation is desired, something like
> fs.openSync() should be used.